# my tezos oracles docker image (tqtezos/oracle-stock-ticker) is unable to find activation code via faucet file

Tags: docker, faucet, python, secret, oracle

my tezos oracles docker image (tqtezos/oracle-stock-ticker) is unable to find activation code from faucet configuration file using flask app.

Getting following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytezos/crypto.py", line 243, in from_faucet
    activation_code=data['secret']
KeyError: 'secret'
```

Faucet config file do not have any secret key.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secret` field was changed to `activation_code` when the faucets moved from https://faucet.tezos.com to https://teztnets.xyz.

Try to open a ticket in their repository: https://github.com/tqtezos/lorentz-contract-oracle/tree/master/stock_ticker